# Errors thrown from here are not handled because the enclosing catch is not exhaustive

Tags: json, swift, error-handling, compiler-errors

[Swift Errors Thrown from here are not handled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30817107/swift-errors-thrown-from-here-are-not-handled)

I followed the above link but i still seeing that issue. Adding code below

```
do {
    // print("\(v)")
    let jsonData = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(["code":"102", "response":v], options: NSJSONWritingOptions.PrettyPrinted)
    let string: String! = String(data: jsonData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding);
    print("\(string)")
    BonjourClient.sharedInstance.sendString(string)
}
catch let error as NSError {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: What version of Xcode are you using? I used to see this in older versions (because the compiler didn't realize that dataWithJSONObject only throws NSErrors), but I can't reproduce it with 7.2.

Comment: Hey  @RobNapier Xcode Version which i am using is 7.2.

Comment: The problem is that it is possible to throw errors that aren't `NSError`, and you're not handling those. I'm just surprised that I'm not seeing the error, at least in a playground. (I'd noticed earlier this week that I wasn't seeing that error in my code, which surprised me.)

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 5**

```swift
enum MyError: Error {
    case somePattern
}

// … 

do {
    let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: /*…*/)
} catch MyError.somePattern {
    print("Some specific known error type occured.")
} catch { // exhaustive. not constrained to any specific error
    print("Unexpected, not otherwise caught, error: \(error)")
}
```

**Swift 4**

```swift
enum MyError: Error {
    case somePattern
}

// … 

do {
    let jsonData = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject([/*…*/])
} catch MyError.somePattern {
    print("Some specific known error type occured.")
} catch { // exhaustive. not constrained to any specific error
    print("Unexpected, not otherwise caught, error: \(error)")
}
```

Note that `error` is available in the final `catch` clause example above.

See [*The Swift Programming Language* Error Handling](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ErrorHandling.html)

> If no pattern is matched, the error gets caught by the final `catch` clause and is bound to a local `error` constant.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you missing an empty catch, and should add:

```
catch {
}
```